# Wrong font behaviour in Inkscape

Tags: fonts, inkscape, text, kerning

I used Fira Sans font (free Google font) and got this:

[image]

Manual kerns are clear, although if I add 0.01 px of Horizontal kerning to "r" then it looks like it should. There is no such problem with other fonts in Inkscape as well as no problem with this font in other apps.